# UPDATE query that does not take into account upper and lower case

Tags: sql, case

I need to update some tables in my database, replacing one word with another, but the problem is that it doesn't have to be case sensitive. I don't want to have to do a consultation for every combination of upper and lower case:

```
UPDATE theme SET message = REPLACE(message,'ToreCube','star');
UPDATE theme SET message = REPLACE(message,'Torecube','star');
UPDATE theme SET message = REPLACE(message,'toreCube','star');
UPDATE theme SET message = REPLACE(message,'torecube','star');
```

I would also like the spaces between words to be indistinguishable, for example:

```
UPDATE theme SET message = REPLACE(message,'Tore Cube','star');
UPDATE theme SET message = REPLACE(message,'ToreCube','star');
```

What would be the UPDATE query that does not take into account upper and lower case and does not take into account spaces?

Thank you

Comment: What's your dbms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LOWER(), if you are using `SQLServer`, this will make your column data lower case, then use lower cases in your replacement string.

```
UPDATE theme SET [message] = REPLACE(LOWER([message]),'tore cube','star');
UPDATE theme SET [message] = REPLACE(LOWER([message]),'torecube','star');
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the type of database management system, but it should be a combination of 'lower' and 'trim' functions wrapped around your string.

Comment: Thank you, can you please tell me what the example would be like taking into account this query?
UPDATE theme SET message = REPLACE(message,'ToreCube','star');

Comment: I use PostgreSQL, so that'd look like this "UPDATE theme SET message = REPLACE(message, LOWER(TRIM('ToreCube')), 'star');"

Comment: But this will only match if the string is lowercase inside `message`, won’t it?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson correct and in that case, convert message to lowercase too to have a match i.e LOWER(TRIM(message))

Answer (score 0):

Use regex replace instead to do case insensitive replacement

```
regexp_replace(message, ‘torecube’, ’star’, ‘i’)
```

The last argument, ‘i’, makes it case insensitive

*I just realized PostgreSQL was not mentioned by OP so we don’t know if this is the dbms. I’ll leave my answer for now until we know*

Answer (score 0):

As we are not sure which RDMS OP uses I would like to present a possible solution that works in a SQL-Server environment:

```
UPDATE theme SET message = 
  REPLACE(REPLACE(message,'tore cube','star'),'torecube','star');
```

In SQL-server the standard setting is case-insensitive. This makes it relatively easy to address the cases when we want a replacement to happen, see here for a little demo:
http://rextester.com/XGYX82444